# Laravel 7.x Middleware(can:gatename) it actually prevent everyone to access a certain page. What did i do wrong?

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-middleware

I tried making an authorization function roles with admin, sales, and users in it. And I make several gate rules. These are so far that I did.

**App\User**

```
public function Roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}

public function hasAnyRoles($roles)
{
if ($this->roles()->whereIn('name', $roles)->first()) {
        return true;
    }
        return false;

}
```

**UsersController**

```
public function index()
{
    $users= User::all();
    return view('admin.users.index')->with('users', $users);
}and the other user's role as well.
```

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
Gate::define('manageUsers', function($user){
    return $user->hasAnyRoles(['admin, sales']);
});
```

**routes\web**

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->middleware('can:manageUsers')->group(function(){

    Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController', ['except' =>['show', 'store', 'create']]);
});
```

and this is the problem

> ->middleware('can:manageUsers')

after I put this into my route I can't access the *admin.users.index.php*, and I thought and I want to kick any other Users Role except admin, and sales from *admin.users.index.php*

but instead of what I thought, it actually kicks everyone out from *admin.users.index.php*

help! how to make admin and sales roles can get in into *admin.users.index.php*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your gate definition, you have

```
Gate::define('manageUsers', function($user){
   return $user->hasAnyRoles(['admin, sales']); //array contains one value 'admin, sales' theres no role like that
});
```

It should be

```
Gate::define('manageUsers', function($user){
  return $user->hasAnyRoles(['admin', 'sales']); //array listed with 2 items. 
});
```

Since your gate check is currently checking if the user has a role called "admin, sales", the check will return false. Of course the assumption from the belongsToMany is that that your users will have many roles and each individual role like 'admin' and 'sales' are attached to the user through the belongsToMany relationship

Comment: glad i could help